# Using environment properties in ant

Tags: java, jenkins, ant, environment-variables

It's probably a trivial question but I'm puzzled by the use of the environment in Ant. I want to update a target which I know works fine on Jenkins, and I need to test my change locally before pushing to prod. However, Ant does not seem to want to read my environment variables even when I write a trivial target such as :

```
<target name="test">
    <property environment="env" />
    <echo>
        ${env.user.country}
        ${env.user.language}
        ${env.TARGET}
    </echo>
</target>
```

which prints

```
Buildfile: /home/local/ANT/.../Workplace/dra/draModelsConfig/build.xml

test:
     [echo] 
     [echo]             ${env.user.country}
     [echo]             ${env.user.language}
     [echo]             ${env.TARGET}
     [echo]         

BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 0 seconds
```

I call the target exactly how the Jenkins host logs it in the build log (simplified for this question):

```
ant -file build.xml -DTARGET=build test
```

Why doesn't `env` contain the environment variables as it should ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714006/environmental-variables-in-ant-script-not-working

Comment: @Andrei_N does not help, look at my code, it already includes the `property` task

Comment: It may print in such way because variables wasn't set

Comment: Yep it does, but the question is why ? I thought the `-DTARGET`, for example, would set it in the environment. As for the other properties, they are set in the environment of my OS

Comment: You are mixing normal property like access with environment. user.country and user.language are available in Java process. So you can access them without env prefix. say ... ${user.country}

Comment: Yep, I could observe that after posting this question. What happened is I know nothing about ANT, so I inferred the expected behaviour from the Jenkins command setting parameters using `-D` and the ANT scripts reading the same properties from the environment. I guess the command is just deceiving and is not actually the reason why these parameters make their way to the environment so that the script runs fine on Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the command:

```
ant -file build.xml -DTARGET=build test
```

`-DTARGET=build` is setting a *property* named `TARGET`, not an environment variable.

`TARGET` can be echo'ed like a regular property:

### build.xml

```
<project name="ant-echo-command-line-prop">
    <echo>My TARGET: ${TARGET}</echo>
</project>
```

### Output

```
$ ant -DTARGET=build
[echo] My TARGET: build
```

Comment: Ok I see, then I don't get why Jenkins runs the command I included in the question. It must set the parameter of the build before running the target, because the ant target we definitely reads for the environment. I think your answer is ok although it does not tell me about Jenkins, since you explain why this ant target does not do what I thought it should do